# Viewport wireframe hatched faces?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

I need help to have viewport wireframe hatched faces like this ?

thx in advance !

Comment: Can you be more specific as to exactly what you mean? - That view is set to wireframe with Shift-Z. but I'm not sure whether you want something else?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. indeed I would like to see the volumes hashed because currently, I only see the edges and it is difficult to understand what I am doing ... 


I see this " https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/478561iD59E958C55E43C3D/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999 " on my viewport I would like to see the hashed faces as well (as in the image above)

Comment: @JohnEason I would like this effect with the hatched faces once the wireframe mode is activated SHIFT+Z, because with the supprposition of a reference plane the edges merge with the plane in wireframe mode. Black on black it's complicated to see clearly but with the hatched faces it's much simpler and more practical to handle in wireframe mode :)

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible. The whole point of wireframe mode in Blender is to completely remove the visibility of faces  so that you can see the complete framework of the model. There's no "halfway house" allowing you to view some of the faces hatched.

Comment: @JohnEason 
this is necessarily possible because in this video this person applies this method: https://youtu.be/l5tIjaDJDlw?list=PLYVR0A4acpNaFiTL-qmxH8fm4DJxqq-vp&t=917

Comment: You have the answer from @Crantisz below! The tutorial was using version 2.80.17 which is way out of date now.

Answer (score 0):

This is old pre 2.80 alpha/beta visualization. You were able to get this result while having reference at background and enable half-transparent x-ray. In modern versions, this behavior was considered to be bad and removed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !